# When using MobX is it better to have more small stores, or fewer large stores?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I prefer splitting logic and having more stores that each manage specific sets of data, but are there any performance considerations I should keep in mind when architecting my MobX state?

Is it generally considered better practice to use more small stores, or fewer large stores? Is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: This is a non-answer, but don't optimize prematurely. Do what makes the most logical sense for the application. Mobx is generally going to have a negligible performance impact in any case.

Answer (score 1):

yes you should use more small stores,sometime you should combination of them

```
class LargeStore{
  aStore= new AStore()
  bStore= new BStore()
  ...
}
```